# Unable to process lookupSoftwareForBundleId request at this time due to a general error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I keep getting this error message when trying to validate my app archive (tried multiple apps, multiple archives, etc) in Xcode. What is going on? I've tried everything including rebooting my computer, checking internet connection, rebuilding the archives, trying older archives that worked before, trying different apps all together ... is something wrong on Apple's side?

**Edit** Added similar screenshot of the same error message from Application Loader

[image: Error message in Xcode when validating]

[image: Error message in Application Loader after exporting archive for app-store]

**Update** Apple must have fixed something because everything started working again a couple hours ago. I assume since it hasn't fixed everyone's situation all at once it must be its something they are fixing in batches for different accounts? I have no solution to offer other than time to wait - I did nothing different and it just started working (I kept trying every hour it seems for over 2 days) until it worked.

[image: Validations working again!]

Comment: I've been receiving this as well.  There's also a small thread in apple's dev forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1097348  I am assuming it is something on apple's side, but hoping someone will give more information on this!

Comment: Out of idle curiosity, is this a cordova app?

Comment: No,  it is a Titanium app however. Not sure how that would make any difference. Something seems to have happened on the Apple side as of yesterday - that's when this all started for us and apparently others as well.

Comment: I am still getting this issue, has anyone here found a solution or has it started working for you? @Streamline

Comment: It started working for me a couple hours ago actually - I think Apple must be fixing something across their system and its affecting different accounts at different times.

Comment: I'm getting this error now, is it likely to be the same thing?

Comment: @DanGreen same here. Hopefully it will resolve itself soon.

Comment: @mxcl Are you using Cordova?

Comment: I am using cordova and have this problem

Answer (score 5):

This is an Apple problem. Sit on it for a couple hours and try it again.

Why do I say this? I'm having the problem now and by the time I did a Google search on it, there are 2 people in the last 30min commenting on the question saying "I've got this problem too" but before that, the question hasn't been active for a month.

Answer (score 1):

Try to archive and export your App manually and upload via Application Loader. This workaround worked for me.

Comment: I get the same message in Application Loader when I try that.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you don't have created app on itunes.

> To successfully upload your mac app from Application Loader you must
>   have to create your app at https://developer.apple.com/ and
>   https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ with same application identifier and application name

Answer (score 0):

So I was having the same problem.
And it turns out, the issue was on my configuration.

What I did wrong was: My distribution profile was no set write, I did a few 
Firs I tried to use a * wildcard application id for.
Second my application id in my xcode was not matching the one on apple developer site.

What I did to solve was. I deleted my provision profile, and created a new distribution one, with a new application id. I made sure that application ID was set on my xode, and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago, it seems I had used an old bundle identifier which is not used anymore.

I just changed my Bundle Identifier on Xcode to the correct updated one. I archived/build again and successfully uploaded to the app store.